# Partial branch coverage in Sonar with JaCoCo when iterating over enum's values

Tags: java, for-loop, enums, sonarqube, jacoco

In SonarQube I notice surprising behavior with constructs such as

```
for (final MyEnum myEnum : MyEnum.values()) {
    ...
}
```

where `MyEnum` is a custom `enum` defined in my project. The line containing the `for` statement is shown as an uncovered branch even though the surrounding code and the body of the loop are marked as covered (and indeed they are run by at least one test).

I do not understand this behavior. Since `values()` return `MyEnum[]`, internally, this kind of `for` loop should evaluate to something equivalent to `for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {` where `values` would be the result of `values()` stored into a temporary variable. Clearly there is a branch here but since there are more than 0 elements in the array, both the branch which enters the loop and the branch which breaks it get executed.

So why do I not see this line as having complete branch coverage?

Comment: Does adding a test with an empty collection help?

Comment: What do you mean by "a test with an empty collection"?

Comment: It might not be possible using `MyEnum.values()`, but I was just curious if adding a test with an empty iterable in the for-each loop would make the branch show up as covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This surprising result from Sonar was a misinterpretation on my side. Lack of branch coverage was caused by lack of code coverage in this particular method. Since the code was not covered at all (contrary to what I first thought and wrote in the question), neither could be the branch in the for-loop.